# How can we Test or reproduce DST move 1hour ahead issue C#.Net and Sql Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, wcf

- summary:

I am trying summaries the issue, Issue is SQL server Table had an "invalid" time stamp in them. It was considered invalid after the date/time did not exist when the clocks moved 1 hour ahead at 2:00am. The entry that caused the issue time stamps of 02:58am  on 03/13/2016. When the time change occurred and the clocks moved forward, these times are essentially in the past now which caused the issue.

- Question:

issue occurred on 03/13/2016 but reported after long time, I want reproduce this again in my local env ?  I db i am using string field for datetime and in C#.Net DateTime object.

I gone through so many blogs i think we know the solution but how can we ensure that every thing is working with reproduce this issue ..

[Check if daylight savings is in effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665678/check-if-daylight-savings-is-in-effect)
[.net adds one hour to summer dst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904806/net-adds-one-hour-to-summer-dst)

Comment: *Instead* of DateTime, use DateTimeOffset and avoid any assumptions about offsets. Just like codepages, there's no way to guarantee that you'll get everything right if 2 offsets are involved (3 if you count UTC, the only kind of DateTime you can depend on)

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis Kanavos, I agreed and this is the perfect solution to use DateTimeOffset but this problem occurs during DST only my Que is how can i reproduce it. even i tried in code and i put break point at int a then i moved time 1 hour ahead of my system even after that its not throughing error it is giving wrong value but not error as "invalid date"
static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   DateTime s1 = DateTime.Now;
   int a = 1/2;//just break point 
   DateTime s2 = DateTime.Now;
   TimeSpan e = s1 - s2;
   Console.Write(e);
   Console.ReadLine();
  }